# What does "trim" mean in "apply()"?

Tags: r

What does the argument "trim" mean in "apply()"?

[For example,](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) I would like to calculate the mean of each column of an array `x`:

```
apply(x, 2, mean, trim = .2)
```

How is it different from

```
apply(x, 2, mean)
```

Which one shall I use?

If I would like to calculate the standard deviation of each column of an array `x`, which one shall I use

```
apply(x, 2, sd, trim = .2)
```

or

```
apply(x, 2, sd)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `trim` argument is not to do with `apply`, but to do with `mean`.

From `?mean`:

> `trim`: the fraction (0 to 0.5) of observations to be trimmed from each end of x before the mean is computed. Values of trim outside that range are taken as the nearest endpoint.

`sd` doesn't have an argument named `trim`, so if you tried `apply(x, 2, sd, trim = .2)` you would get an error about trying to use an unused argument.

---

This is not an argument to `apply`, but it is an argument passed down from `apply` to `mean` using `...`:

From `?apply`:

> `...` : optional arguments to `FUN`.

This adds flexibility and reduces dependence on creating anonymous functions. For example, without the `...` argument, if you wanted to do a trimmed mean, you would have to do:

```
apply(x, 2, function(x) mean(x, trim = .2))
```

Comment: This argument is passed through `apply` function to `mean` function.

Comment: This is common behavior for R functions that take a function as an argument. In the specifications they are captured by `...` and they make building on other functions very intuitive.

Answer (score -1):

Just tried this with dplyr and it seems to work fine.

```
df <- x %>%
    select(V1:V7) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=T, trim=0.2)))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question